# Algorithm for determining if a number ends in 100

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers

Is there a fast math calculation for determining whether or not the given number ends in `100`?

Samples:

```
hasHundred( 5 ) ==> false
hasHundred( 100 ) ==> true
hasHundred( 1000 ) ==> false
hasHundred( 10100 ) ==> true
```

It's fairly trivial using strings and checking for `'100'`, but I'd like to know whether it can be done mathematically.

Comment: Why is it `false` for `1000`?

Comment: Probably `n % 1000 === 100`

Comment: Doesn't contain `100` specifically. If it were `1100` then it would pass.

Comment: So by "contain" you mean "ends with `100` when expressed as a base-10 number", right?

Comment: Just to clarify, `1001` should also be false?

Comment: Yes, that's a much better way of putting it :)

Comment: @Juhana yes.  I think a better way of putting it is, given n1 and n2, does n1 contain n2 at the end of it? That's why I had mentioned that as strings it's very straightforward but I'd like to know whether it can be done with simple math since we're dealing only with numbers. Make sense?

Comment: Yes - in math terms you're looking for numbers congruent to 100 (mod 1000).

Comment: will it pass for `1123`?

Comment: What do you want to happen for negative numbers? Mathematically, -900 is congruent to 100 mod 1000, but you probably would not say that -900 ends in 100.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about a *congruence*. You're looking for numbers of the form

```
100 + k * 1000
```

where `k` is some integer; another way of writing that is numbers for which

```
n % 1000 === 100
```

which means that the remainder after dividing by 1000 must be 100.

Comment: @squint Can you give a use case where it doesn't work?  It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @smaili ---- think this actually nails it!

Comment: @smaili: I was mistaken, which was why I had removed the comment immediately.

Answer (score -3):

Theoretically, every number can be written as a sum of powers of 10.
If that sum starts like this 0 + 0*10^1 + 1*10^2 + ... 
then "it starts with 100" as you define.

Therefore, all you need is an algorithm to write a number in that form.
(Lemme see if i can find something)

And yes, that algorithm is likely to be grossly inefficient --- way more efficient to do strings